# Sales taxes to apply for a Canadian company selling digital subscriptions

Tags: united-states, canada, sales-tax

Let's say I have a web service that is a mail server (I cloned gmail). People pay me 10$ per month to use it. My business in located in Canada. When a Canadian resident sign up, I have to charge local taxes for their province.

When a US resident sign up, what taxes should I charge him?

Is a digital subscription even taxable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific information you need is covered in [B-090 GST/HST and Electronic Commerce](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/gm/b-090/README.html), specifically section V, subscriptions to databases and web sites.

The Government of Canada gives an example of charging for access to an interactive web site, and says [specifically](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/gm/b-090/b-090-01-e.html#P101_17294):

> A supplier makes a Web site featuring digitized content available to
>   subscribers, including information, music, video, games, and
>   activities, whether or not developed or owned by the supplier. The
>   subscribers pay a fixed periodic fee for access to the site. The
>   principal value of the site to subscribers is interacting with the
>   site while on-line, as opposed to getting a product or services from
>   the site.
>
> The subscribers' right to access the content on the Web site is a
>   supply of intangible personal property. In essence it is a supply of a
>   right to use software, and the right to access other digitized content
>   on the Web site. Although a copy of a digitized product is not
>   provided, there is a supply of a right to view, access or use a
>   product while the customer is on-line. As in Example 14, any human
>   involvement occurs behind the scenes in establishing and maintaining
>   the Web site, but there is no human involvement on the part of the
>   supplier when subscribers access the site and its digitized content.

(I snipped a bit about advertising). Thus, your case would be that you are supplying intangible personal property. Intangible personal property is zero-rated, according to [GI-034](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/gi/gi-034/README.html), if you are exporting it to non-registered non-residents (e.g. U.S. residents). That document [explicitly states](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/gi/gi-034/gi-034-e.html):

> Examples of supplies of IPP that will now be eligible for zero-rating
>   under the proposed provision include:
>
> subscriptions to Web sites that provide subscribers with a right to
>   access and use digitized content on the site, such as information in a
>   database or images, and that may also include a right to download a
>   copy of the digitized content;
>
> subscriptions to interactive Web sites
>   that provide subscribers with a right to access and use digitized
>   content, such as games, music and videos, on the sites while they are
>   online;

My understanding, then, is that you would not charge GST or HST to your U.S. customers, but do need to do so to your Canadian customers.

As always, note that I am neither a lawyer nor an accountant. You will want to consult with one or both to ensure the information as I presented is accurate.